# Killing infinite python script from shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Hi i have 5 infinite python script.I want run first script and after 1 hours kill first script and after this run second infinite script and after 1 hours kill second script. Its my codes what is a problem ? how i can ? Please dont recomend me giveng time to python script . I can do id , but its not useful for my project . Only need killing infinite scripts from shell . Thank you very much

> ITS MY SHELL SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/bash

START=`date +%s`
while true
do
    if [ $(( $(date +%s) - 10 )) -lt $START ]; then
        python infinite.py
    else
        pkill python
        break
    fi
done

START=`date +%s`
while true
do
    if [ $(( $(date +%s) - 10 )) -lt $START ]; then
        python infinite.py
    else
        sudo pkill python
        break
    fi
done

START=`date +%s`
while true
do
    if [ $(( $(date +%s) - 10 )) -lt $START ]; then
        python infinite.py
    else
        pkill python
        break
    fi
done
```

> ITS MY PYTHON SCRIPT

```
x = 0
while True:
    print("Hello, World ! " + str(x))
    x +=1
```

Comment: $START is not assigned a value in your code.

Comment: i edited sorry,but with start not worked

Answer (score 1):

GNU coreutils comes with a `timeout` tool.

To run five scripts, infinite1.py to infinite5.py, for one hour each in sequence:

```
for script in infinite_{1..5}.py
do
   timeout 1h python "$script"
done
```

Comment: Thaaaankk Youuuuu very much friend.I am lost 4-5 hours for it,its work

Answer (score 0):

This code will run your script in the background during an hour and then kill the process

```
START=$(date '+%s')
python infinite.py &
while true
do
    if [ $(( $(date '+%s') - $START )) -lt 3600 ]; then
        echo "Still running"
    else
        pkill -f 'infinite.py'
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Fixed the answer for the sake of correctness but that-other-guy's one is better ;)

Comment: Please don't recommend users to use `pkill` as `pkill python` without warnings!

Comment: You are right @emily-e, fixed to kill by script name.